# Search and notify for duplicates in a groupbox containing multiple textboxes

Tags: c#, linq, validation

I have a groupbox control containing 5 textboxes.

As a part of validation process I have to check for duplicate entries every time the user enters something in the text box.

I've stored these textboxes references in a generic list i.e. `List<TextBox>` 
For ex: I have named the list as **uniqueIdList**.

For checking the duplicate entry, I rely on the Validated event provided by the TextBox control.

i.e. whenever the user enters a text and moves to another control, the OnValidated event is invoked by the control. I handle this event to check for the duplicates.

i.e.

```
private void txtID1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtID1.Text != string.Empty)
            {
                ValidateDuplicateId(sender);
            }
        }
```

The **ValidateDuplicateId**() method

```
        private void ValidateDuplicateId(object sender)
        {
            errProviderDuplicateID.Clear();
            TextBox input = (TextBox)sender;
       if(uniqueIdList.GroupBy(tb => tb.Text)
.Where(gp => gp.Skip(1).Any()).Count() > 1)
            {
                errProviderDuplicateID.SetError((TextBox)sender,"Duplicate ID");
                errProviderDuplicateID.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.AlwaysBlink;
            }
        }
```

So, whenever the user enters a text inside the field, the textbox controls fires a validated event. I invoke ValidateDuplicateId() in each of the event handler by passing the reference of the textbox.

The ValidateDuplicateId method, basically checks for the duplicates (if there are more than 1 occurrences of the same text) and raises an error using an errorprovider control.

Although, the above approach works sort of OK, somehow I'm not very much convinced with the implementation. Can anyone of you suggest a better approach to tackle this issue.

Thanks in advance
VATSAG

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your approach is quite nice!

I, personally, would put all the textboxes in one container and just go over panels children of textbox type, instead of initializing a list of them.

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> allTextBoxes = myContainer.Children.OfType<TextBox>();
```

But that's not a **must**, that's just my on preference.

**Edit**

You could check for duplicates with *Distinct* LINQ extension.

```
IEnumerable<TextBox> containerTextboxes = myContainer.Children.OfType<TextBox>();

int initialCounter = containerTextboxes.Count();
int distinctCounter = containerTextboxes.Select(tb => tb.Text).Distinct();

if (initialCounter == distinctCounter)
{
    // No duplicates
}
else
{
    // There are duplicates
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what would you do differently to validate for duplicate text entries. ?

Comment: Just added to my answer an edit with an example with using a distinct LINQ extension method.
Check this, although I think that your approach is better.